# How to define variables inside a GeometryReader in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to calculate the line width of a shape inside a view based on the view's size. Looking through various posts here on StackOverflow, I think the solution is to use a GeometryReader like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
           // Here goes your view content,
           // and you can use the geometry variable
           // which contains geometry.size of the parent
           // You also have function to get the bounds
           // of the parent: geometry.frame(in: .global)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I define variables inside the GeometryReader construct to be used for the view? I've tried to put a var statement directly after the line "GeometryReader { geometry in", but this gives a compiler error.

Comment: Clarification: are you trying to find the dimensions of `MyView`, or its parent? Is `MyView` the "line width of a shape" (where `GeometryReader` would be the dimensions of the parent view) or is this "shape" a child `View` inside `MyView`?

Comment: Basically, don't forget the *everything* in `SwiftUI` is a `View` - it sounds like you are trying to work with a `CAShapeLayer` frame based on the `UIView` dimensions.

Comment: The answer bellow just solves what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be a function builder related bug (as of Beta 3), and I recommend filing feedback on it.

The workaround I've been using is to use `GeometryProxy` in a separate method with an explicit return.

```swift
var body: some View {
  GeometryReader { proxy in
    self.useProxy(proxy)
  }
}

func useProxy(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
  var width = proxy.size.width
  return VStack {
    // use width in here
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe I'm still seeing this in beta 7.